# Exception handling around shift in Scala

Tags: scala, continuation-passing

Scala 2.10.2. Running

```
import util.continuations._
import concurrent.ops._

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        reset {
            try {
                shift { cont: (Unit => Unit) => {
                    spawn {
                        throw new Exception("blah")
                        cont()
                    }
                }}
                println("after shift")
            } catch {
                case e: Exception => println(e)
            }
            println("reset end")
        }
    }
}
```

Gives

```
Cont.scala:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Unit @scala.util.continuations.cpsParam[Unit,Unit]
                case e: Exception => println(e)
                                            ^
one error found
```

If I remove the try/catch block everything's fine.  I'm still trying to figure out how continuations work in Scala, but this one totally eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

Just stating the obvious - It is a *Scala type inference meets cps-annotation* problem. The catch block do not contain any cps annotated expression. In this case the catch-block is expected to be of the same type as the try-block:

```
Unit @cps[Unit] // same as Unit @cpsParam[Unit,Unit]
```

To my experience, the type-inference and the CPS-transformation in Scala does not always work as expected and things that work in one version of Scala do not work in another version.

There exists workarounds such as the **try_protector** mentioned in [Scala Continuations - Why can't my shifted call be inside a try-catch block?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12662113/2583880)

Not sure if it helps in your case (i.e. Scala version 2.10.2).

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend the try/catch statement to catch `Exception("blah")`?

Even if it compiled, `spawn` which is deprecated would happen on another thread before the flow gets to running the  continuation.

Without the try/catch you have something like this:

```
println("in main " + Thread.currentThread())
reset {
  shift { cont: (Unit => Unit) =>
    {
      spawn {
        println("in spawned " + Thread.currentThread())
        cont()
      }
    }
  }
  println("after shift " + Thread.currentThread())
  println("reset end")
}
```

}

The `cont` function is the reified portion of code which corresponds to this function:

```
val cont = () => {
  println("after shift " + Thread.currentThread())
  println("reset end")
}
```

So when you do `spawn { cont() }`, you just run the two `println` in a new separate thread. Running the program, I get:

```
in main Thread[main,5,main]
in spawned Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
after shift Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
reset end
```

That shows that the continuation ran on a separate thread. Now if you insert a `throw new Exception()` before `cont()`, then all you get is an exception thrown on the spawned thread (where apparently the exception would be swallowed).

Would running the continuation inside a try/catch and having an exception thrown after the `shift` be more what you are trying to do?

```
reset {
  shift { cont: (Unit => Unit) =>
    spawn {
      println("in spawned " + Thread.currentThread())
      try { cont() }
      catch { case e: Exception => println(e) }
    }
  }
  println("after shift " + Thread.currentThread())
  throw new Exception("blah")
  println("reset end")
}
```

}

This prints:

```
in main Thread[main,5,main]
in spawned Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
after shift Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
java.lang.Exception: blah
```